# Adding AAR in IntelliJ IDEA without gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aar

How can I add aar-module into the project in IDEA (without gradle, using ant)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in android studio go to `file/new/new module`
then 
select
new module from existing aar package

Comment: He is not asking about android studio

Comment: It will be similar in Intellij

Comment: I had to unzip it before I could add it as a new module from sources. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

With Android Studio, that is pretty the same, the only solution I found was to extract the .aar content in a folder to use with the import module procedure. (`File -> Project Structure... -> Modules -> + button -> Import module`)

If that doesn't work check if in the above extracted folder there is a .jar file and try to load it as external library (`File -> Project Structure... -> Libraries`)