# Add AAR file as dependency to Intellj project

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 to make an Android project after moving from Android Studio a while back. I made some libraries (through Android Studio) and would like to use them in Intellij.

However, it seems that Intellij only accepts `.jar` files through the `libs` folder, and Android Studio only creates `.aar` files.

In Android Studio, one has the option (when creating a new module) to import an existing `.jar/.aar` package to be put into a new module. This option doesn't seem to be in intellij. [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31448049/1085937) seems to think that Intellij supports that, but those instructions allow me to create a *brand new* Gradle module. What I want to do is use an existing `.aar` file.

What should I go about doing? Should I move back to Studio for this project, or is there a way for me to use these `.aar` files?

P.S. Intellij can't process raw `aar`s, period. I tried adding this to my gradle files, but got an error:

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
```

**Edit**
Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir() {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ':mylib@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: can you also paste all your gradle.build file ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech I've also put in the suggestions from the website you linked, but now I get an error thrown on the `preDexDebug` phase of the gradle build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I saw this option in Intellj called "Associate file..." and associated the aar with an archive. Upon recompile I got this error

```
Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: mylib.aar
```

I guess it's only jars for Intellij. Back to Android Studio, I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you can create .jar files with Android Studio as well, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19484146/550393) but .aars are awesome and enable you to do more then what you could with a jar

I have not used Intellij IDEA but I assume you have a gradle.build file in your project? If the name of your aar file is

> my_lib_1.0.0.aar

and its under the libs directory then try the following in your gradle.build file:

```
compile(name:'my_lib_1.0.0', ext:'aar')
```

Comment: I just get a `Failed to resolve :my_lib_1.0.0:` (I subbed my library name for the placeholder)

Comment: when you right-click your .aar file do you have any option like 'add library to project' or 'add to build path' ?

Comment: any particular reasons you are not using Android Studio ? My answer should give you no problems in Android Studio

Comment: Nope. In fact, intellij actually spit this out at me just now: `Warning:Project app: Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: mylib.aar`

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio because Intellij gives me a lot of flexibility with what I want to do, and now I've gotten too used to it to go back to AS :)

Comment: this link might help, check the build.gradle file: http://adanware.blogspot.com/2014/06/android-importing-google-play-services.html